# Rails 3 - How do I remove database tables that have been created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I created 2 models and ran the migrations, attempted some work on each of them and now I would like to start over and approach them differently. I'm new to Rails and have never attempted to delete/remove database tables (apart from rolling them back right after I migrated them).

Thanks!

Comment: See the top answer to the question [Rails - How to ReCreate the database][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116067/rails-how-to-recreate-the-database

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create another migration and in self.up

```
drop_table :tablename
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-drop_table

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why this didn't come up in my searches.

Answer (score 6):

To drop a table during a migration, you can `rails g migration DropUsers`

```
class DropUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    drop_table :users
  end

  def down
    # recreate table logic here
  end
end
```

You can also drop tables from the Rails console

```
ActiveRecord::Migration.drop_table(:users)
```

FYI If you want to remove scaffold-created code, `rails destroy scaffold User`

Answer (score 1):

If you never committed the changes or deployed the app, you can simply remove the model files and remove the tables from your database using the database console (assuming it's sqlite3 type `sqlite3` to enter the shell console) or a database administration GUI.

Otherwise, you will need to use the `drop_table` migration to reflect the changes on the production system.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if I could use SQLite DB Browser to just delete the tables. Can I just delete old migration files as well?

Answer (score 0):

See the top answer to the question [Rails - How to ReCreate the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116067/rails-how-to-recreate-the-database)