# $ bundle exec rake db:reset command raising couldn't drop db/development.sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, railstutorial.org

I tried to run `$ bundle exec rake db:reset` and found the following on console

```
Couldn't drop db/development.sqlite3 : #<Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - c:/sample_app/db/development.sqlite3>
db/development.sqlite3 already exists
-- create_table("users", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.3940s
-- add_index("users", ["email"], {:name=>"index_users_on_email", :unique=>true})

   -> 0.1280s
-- initialize_schema_migrations_table()
   -> 0.0010s
-- assume_migrated_upto_version(20120419034627, ["c:/sample_app/db/migrate
"])
   -> 0.0040s
```

How can I solve it?

**Edit** I was following a tutorial and it tells me to run the above command to delete all the data from the database safely. And I am also using admin account.

Comment: Check this out. This will be helpful

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116067/rails-how-to-recreate-the-database

Comment: Thanks for the information but, they are talking about the commands but I have the command which is outputting the above error message

Answer (score 42, accepted):

When you do [`db:reset`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.1.4/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake#L244), it's running `db:drop` and `db:setup` in sequence. Your [error message](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.1.4/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake#L145) indicates that `db/development.sqlite` couldn't be deleted.

If you're on Windows, maybe you need to stop your Rails server and console. Otherwise, figure out what's preventing the file from being deleted. It could be permission problem. A reboot may solve the problem too.

Comment: I restarted everything that uses rails resource and everything is fine now.

Comment: Had the same problem, stopping the rails server was all I needed to do. Thanks!

Comment: this answer is correct! I had the same problem and stopping the server for awhile make the command works.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I just had this problem (continued sqlite3 issues with Windows), and while rebooting, shutting the command line, and stopping the server didn't work, I did manage to solve it by actually running each of the commands htanta mentioned above sequentially: 
1. bundle exec rake db:drop
2. bundle exec rake db:create
3. bundle exec rake db:migrate

If db:reset is only these commands anyway, I don't understand why it doesn't work but the individual commands do?

Comment: see my comment above. try `db:migrate:reset` to run all of those commands.

Comment: Thank you, @grist. Breaking up the commands worked when nothing else would.

Answer (score 1):

Have been trying to resolve the same issue. Stopping Rails Server on Windows didn't help, but restarting the whole environment did the trick, bundle exec rake db:reset went through, but be sure not to start your server before that as it will call the same error.
Continue with

```
$ bundle exec rake db:reset
$ bundle exec rake db:populate
$ bundle exec rake test:prepare
```

and start Rails Server after that.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible answer is that you have a database file open. Close those files and stop your server, and it should work.

Answer (score -1):

For Dropping entire database just give rake db:setup it drops and again creates the database for you