# Rails - rake db:reset not clearing my database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

New to rails here, and experimenting with using the db\seeds.rb file and such

First, I want to clear all the data in my database using `rake db:reset` but it's not working!

Here's my output

```
C:\Sites\sportproject>rake db:reset
Couldn't drop db/development.sqlite3 : #
db/development.sqlite3 already exists
-- create_table("sports", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0640s
-- create_table("teams", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0340s
-- add_index("teams", ["sport_id"], {:name=>"index_teams_on_sport_id"})
   -> 0.0160s
-- initialize_schema_migrations_table()
   -> 0.0000s
-- assume_migrated_upto_version(20130531012951, ["C:/Sites/sportproject/db/migra
te"])
   -> 0.0000s
```

Then I log into my console with `rails console` and type `Sport.all` (Sport is the name of one of my models) and it's showing there's still data!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290557/bundle-exec-rake-dbreset-command-raising-couldnt-drop-db-development-sqlite3

Comment: Thank you. That seems to be the case with me

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in Patrik's link.

It's because I'm on windows, as the database is possibly being used by another process, hence the "Permission Denied" message. I just needed to ensure no other processes were using the database.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Linux and postgresql you can do

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

and then

```
rake db:reset
```

I think with mysql is

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The reason was because I was running the rake db:reset on my IRB or Console. Instead, I quit out of console and run the code again and it worked. Perhaps Itll work for you too.