# Rails - Mysql database already exists but it doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying run a rake db:create and it says that the database already exists (I never created this database before, this a new project). When I run rake db:migrate it says "Unknown database". I checked the mysql database (show databases;) and that database really does not exist.

Anyone knows what is that? I searched for solutions but without success.

When I run rake db:create

```
rake db:create
Celluloid 0.17.3 is running in BACKPORTED mode. [ http://git.io/vJf3J ]
adimax_development already exists
adimax_test already exists
```

When I run rake db:migrate

```
rake db:migrate
Celluloid 0.17.3 is running in BACKPORTED mode. [ http://git.io/vJf3J ]
rake aborted!
Mysql2::Error: Unknown database 'adimax_development'
```

database.yml

```
development:
 adapter: mysql2
 encoding: utf8
 database: adimax_development
 pool: 5
 username: root
 password:
```

Error:
[Error image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfgyH.png)

Comment: what does your `database.yml` file define as the host and port? That file will tell Rails how to connect to the MySql db server

Comment: can you post your database.yml file ?

Comment: @sameera207 I updated the question with my database.yml. Thanks

Comment: @Darkisa I updated the question with my database.yml. Thanks

Comment: Are you able to go into the mysql instance with `rails dbconsole`?

Comment: @LeoCorrea when a run command **rails dbconsole** the following error occurs:

**rails dbconsole 
Celluloid 0.17.3 is running in BACKPORTED mode. [ http://git.io/vJf3J ]
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'adimax_development'**

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I got solve this creating the database directly in mysql.

I entered in mysql with `mysql -u root` and than I run "CREATE DATABASE adimax_development;". After this I comeback to my application and run rake db:migrate and that worked.

Thanks to all those who have been willing to help.

Answer (score 5):

Try executing this command:

```
rake db:drop db:create db:migrate
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4116124/9336629

Comment: When I try a "rake db: drop" the Rails says that the database is unknown, but when I try created a new one, he says the database already exists.

Comment: Did you try db:reset then db:migrate ?

Comment: Yes, but he says tha the database is unknow.

Comment: You should also be able to do that with `rake db:{drop,create,migrate}`